# Nash point and Limit point

Tags: convex-optimization

I have taken an optimization course but It seems that I don't have its basics  so any reference would be appreciated,

In the [publication](http://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/d164/df3c7450e3317350038ea2fa8fd04ae39eff.pdf) , it is stated

> any limit point satisfies the Nash equilibrium conditions.

After reading I knew that Nash equilibrium is related to game theory where one of 2 participants can't gain by change of strategy as long as as the other participant is on the same strategy.

I also found that limit point is the stationary point and in other documents that it is the result of the limits operation, where a point doesn't exist in a set but tends to get close to it.

My problem is that I can't relate both of them.

Definition of Nash point in the paper in page 6 for objective function,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x \in \mathcal{X} }{\text{minimize}}
& & F(x_1, ...,x_s) = f(x_1,...,x_s) + \sum_{i=1}^s (r_i(x_i)) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & F(x_i) \geqslant 0 , \quad where  \quad i = 1, ...,s
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

is

\begin{equation*}
F(x^*_1,x_{i-1}^*,x_i^*,x_{i+1}^*,...,x_s^*) \leqslant F(x^*_1,x_{i-1}^*,x_i,x_{i+1}^*,...,x_s^*), \forall x_i \in \mathcal{X_i^*} \\ 
\mathcal{X_i^*} = \mathcal{X_i}(x_1^*,...,x_{i-1}^*,x_{i+1}^*,...,x_s^*)
\end{equation*}

where $x_i^*$ is a Nash point.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that your article can be viewed without a subscription. Regardless, it's not good Math.SE practice to require readers to rely on reading external articles to get the necessary context for a question or answer. Please consider providing more details surrounding the claim (specifically, what the limit point is _of_). (I'm aware that the abstract itself has this claim, but the article claims to explain and prove it.)

Comment: @MichaelGrant, Sorry for the confusion, I edited the link for access to the article. I hope if its possible to elaborate the relation between the stationary point and Nash point. That in the case that the limit point is the stationary points.